# ObservableCollection item amount in XAML

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How to bind ObservableCollection item amount in
I'm using ObservableCollection for selecting items to the cart.

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemInCart> ItemsInCart
    {
        get { return _itemsInCart; }
        set { Set(ref _itemsInCart, value); }
    }
...
XAML:
cm:Message.Attach="[Event ItemClick] = [OnSellingItemSelected($clickedItem)]"
```

After all I'm taking this collection and using navigate send it to the next page.
Trying to show collection amount in TextBlock I faced with problem of updating data.

```
    public string ItemsInCartCount
    {
        get { return _itemsInCart.Count().ToString(); }
    }
...
XAML:
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemsInCartCount, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Recieving new items to ItemsInCart the amount in text box is not changing. How can I bind in a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Recieving new items to ItemsInCart the amount in text box is not changing. How can I bind in a right way?

`ObservableCollection` contains [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1), if we add the new item into the `ObservableCollection`, this event will be triggered. then you could reload  `ItemsInCartCount`.

```
private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ItemsInCartCount =  e.NewItems.Count.ToString();
}
```

Please note: `ItemsInCartCount` will notify the value change, so we need implement `onproperty` change for it.

```
private string _itemsInCartCount;
public string ItemsInCartCount
{
    get { return _itemsInCartCount; }
    set { Set(ref _itemsInCartCount, value); }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it through  Bindings.Update(); Is it good approach or not?

Comment: May be you could share your code, I will test, in general, we use above code to approach.